# can you provide information about websocket

Tags: websocket, iot, sensors

I am doing research on websocket in the world of IoT, but the scope of information I have is quite small. I like the suggestion, if you can share information about the website, if you can, thank you.

I read several papers about IoT, including the application of websocket in the queuing system, there is also a comparative analysis of the performance of Xbee and Websocket.

Answer (score 0):

**WebSocket** is a communications protocol which facilitates a full-duplex communication channel over a single TCP connection. WebSocket WebSocket communication presents a suitable protocol for the IoT environments. Since it offers a lightweight communication between server and client also bundles of data can be transmitted continually between multiple devices. For this we need to have a server that needs WebSocket library installed and also a WebSocket Client and web browser installed on the client or the device that supports WebSocket.

There are both the advantages and caveats of using WebSockets and IoT.
Please refer the below links for more information:

1) https://www.hcltech.com/blogs/unleashing-power-html5-websocket-internet-things-iot

2) https://medium.com/@krishna.thokala2010/websocket-fever-for-iot-f662498ff1d2

3) https://webofthings.org/tag/websockets/

4) https://readwrite.com/2017/10/31/websockets-iot-two-dont-go-together/

Hope this information helps. Please comment if you need more assistance on specific details.